# Fake the current date/timestamp in DB2 LUW for testing

Tags: testing, db2, db2-luw

For (non regression) testing purpose, I frequently need to make DB2 LUW return a "fake" current date.
This is of course due to application code that rely on the current date / timestamp , and which will behave differently  when run during a different date.

We have the possibility to change the operating system (Linux for instance) date , since the testing environment are isolated and dedicated per tester.

Unfortunately, this doesn't help a lot, since we face at least two problems :

1) Binding programs (Cobol) when the system date goes backward gives errors (tables not found, ...)

2) Functions created after the 'past' system date are also not usable....

For the point 1), we can set the date to present , then bind, then come back to past,
But for point 2), I didn't find a workaround.

Does anybody have experience  on this problem ? Any alternatives including free or proprietary software are welcome.

Comment: So essentially you want `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to return an arbitrary value, with the rest of the DB2 instance behaving based on the factual timestamp value?

Comment: Yes, and also current date,   and any other date function that rely on the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, our shop purchased a proprietary utility to assist in testing Year-2000-related program changes.

The software allowed us to specify an arbitrary "current" date and time in our test JCL, using parameters "ALTDATE" and "ALTTIME":

```
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=MYPGM,ALTDATE=MM/DD/YYYY,ALTTIME=HH.MM
```

Program calls to system date routines, like COBOL "ACCEPT . . . FROM DATE" or DB2 "CURRENT TIMESTAMP", would then return values based on a "fake" system clock that started with the specified date and time.

I believe the product also supported use of a simulated clock in CICS regions for testing of on-line applications, but I could be mistaken.  Unfortunately, management decided to stop renewing the product license some time after Y2K had passed, even though several of us developers found it to be very useful for testing date-sensitive logic.

Although I do not know the name of the product we used, a Google search turns up one called "Simulate 2000" by DTS Software that appears to have identical functionality.

Comment: For mainframe (z/OS), I confirm there are some solutions similar to the product you describe like Xpeditor/Xchange from Compuware. We can also change time when using RD&T Z (emulated z/OS on x86 platforms).  What I'm looking for is a solution for open systems (Linux , Unix and Windows)....